# last price for multiple symbols

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, tws

I'm trying to get the last price for multiple symbols using ib_insync package, but I don't know how to pass the `ib` object to the function, and the last price returned from the function is `nan`. This will be single threaded, so I can use a global variable for ib.

```
def last_live_price(ib,symbol_in,exchange_in,currency_in):
        contract=Stock(symbol=symbol_in,exchange=exchange_in,currency=currency_in)        
        last_live=ib.reqMktData(contract, genericTickList='', snapshot=True, regulatorySnapshot=False,mktDataOptions=None)
        time.sleep(5)
        last=last_live.last
        return(last)
    
    
util.startLoop()  # uncomment this line when in a notebook or spynder
ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496,clientId=26)

d = {'symbol':['700', '9988', '2318', '386'],
        'exchange':['SEHK','SEHK','SEHK','SEHK'],
        'currency':['HKD','HKD','HKD','HKD']
        }
hk = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#how should ib object be passed to the function?
hk['last']=hk.apply(lambda x: ib,last_live_price(symbol_in=x['symbol'],
                                 exchange_in=x['exchange'],
                                 currency_in=x['currency']),axis=1)

#how should ib object be passed to the function?
test_last=last_live_price(ib=ib,symbol_in='CBA',exchange_in='ASX',currency_in='AUD')
```

Comment: Which line of code is giving you the error?

Comment: I found that bug - the object returned by ib.reqMktData can't be turned into a dataframe, but I can't pass the ib object to the function. I'll edit the question.

Comment: NameError: name 'pd' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

This code is working: `time.sleep(x)` causes a problem so replace it with `ib.sleep(x)`, and getting the full contract via `ib.qualifyContracts(contract)` is good practice.

```
def last_live_price(symbol_in,exchange_in,currency_in):
        contract=Stock(symbol=symbol_in,exchange=exchange_in,currency=currency_in)  
        ib.qualifyContracts(contract) 
        ib.sleep(5)
        last_live=ib.reqMktData(contract, genericTickList='', snapshot=True, regulatorySnapshot=False,mktDataOptions=None)
        ib.sleep(5)
        last=last_live.last
        return(last)

d = {'symbol':['NAB', 'CBA', 'ANZ', 'ORG'],
        'exchange':['ASX','ASX','ASX','ASX'],
        'currency':['AUD','AUD','AUD','AUD'],
        'last':[None,None,None,None]
        }

stocks = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

stocks['last']=stocks.apply(lambda x: last_live_price(symbol_in=x['symbol'],
                                  exchange_in=x['exchange'],
                                  currency_in=x['currency']),axis=1)
```

Comment: ib.sleep(5) twice is too much, 1second is enough and only once :) (at least for a list <20 I found it to work nice, 0.5seconds however was again too fast

Comment: ib.sleep(5) is better than ib.sleep(2). I stand corrected. I found through experimentation that 2 seconds can sometimes be too quick for the last value to fill. cheers

Comment: IBKR tech has improved, use their new API instead https://interactivebrokers.github.io/cpwebapi/endpoints

Answer (score 0):

```
class IBapi:
    def __init__(self):
        self.order_id = 0
        self.ib = IB()
        self.ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, clientId=1)
        self.ib.reqMarketDataType(3)
        self.req = None
    
    def wait_until_req_is_not_nan(self,time_out=4):
        start_time = time.time()
        while math.isnan(self.req.last) and time.time() - start_time < time_out:
            self.ib.sleep(0.2)
    
    def get_vix_price(self):
        vix = Index('VIX', 'CBOE')
        self.ib.qualifyContracts(vix)
        self.req =  self.ib.reqMktData(vix, '', False, False)
        self.wait_until_req_is_not_nan()
        return self.req.last
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).